# What is XLNC an example of?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

*XS* sounds like *excess*, *B4* sounds like *before*, *XLNC* sounds like *excellency*, etc.  What are these wordplays called?

Comment: You might be interested in William Steig's book *C D B?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some googling, I found the term *[grammagram](http://doncolton.com/dvs/)* referring to this type of wordplay.  While not as common/official as *rebus*, this term is much more specific, since a rebus is usually mostly pictures, with few letters.  It is an RL-coined ([Richard Lederer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Lederer)) word, apparently (see this [thefreelibrary](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/A+dictionary+of+letter+words.-a0111304865) entry), which, together with the comparative rarity of grammagrams themselves, would explain its uncommon status.

Personally, I'd use it, though *[rebus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)* (or *letter rebus*) would be more widely understood.

Comment: The OED doesn't have 'grammagram', but it does have ‘logogram’ – ‘a sign or character representing a word'. It's not clear if the definition can be extended to cover more than one sign or character, but it seems pretty close.

Answer (score 9):

That sort of wordplay is called a [rebus.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)

Comment: A rebus usually has pictures as well.

Comment: True, but pictures are not required to make it a rebus; at the wikipedia link you can see some examples which are all-letter rebuses, just as the OP's are.

Comment: I agree that *rebus* fits the bill, albeit loosely.  I suppose one could say *letter rebus* if one wanted to make it more specific.