# Is there a name for this method of writing that includes pictograms?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, symbols

I've seen people write (usually in a humorous way) a 'code-like' message where parts of words are replaced with a pictogram that sounds like that word-part.  E.G.:

> (eyeball) (tin can)(rope knot) get the (hole in ground) (earth) in my head,
>   yet.

becomes

> I cannot get the whole world in my head, yet.

I once saw this used in a fictional book, and wonder if it has an actual name.

**Edit:** the answer also helped by re-find this [wonderfully imagined race that communicates via rebuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dabus).

Comment: Huh. I was going to say this is probably GR, but most of the search terms I tried ("pictures replacing words" and things like that) don't turn up a ton of easily visible results that say "rebus". Interesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is XLNC an example of?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/what-is-xlnc-an-example-of)

Comment: @Hellion very similar, and thanks for the [rebus/grammatagram index](http://doncolton.com/dvs/) in the answer.

Comment: @Hellion: having the same answer doesn't necessarily imply that the questions are duplicates of each other. If I were looking at a picture puzzle and trying to figure out what it's called, never in a million years would (or *should*) it occur to me to check out a question about telegram-style abbreviations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is called a *[rebus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)*:

> A rebus is an allusional device that uses pictures to represent words
>   or parts of words. It was a favourite form of heraldic expression used
>   in the Middle Ages to denote surnames, for example in its basic form 3
>   salmon fish to denote the name "Salmon".

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Actually, heraldry that makes a visual pun on the bearer's name is called ***canting*** arms. Yes, you could make the argument that a cant is a type of rebus, but it's still not correct to imply that the word "rebus" is widely used in heraldry.

Comment: Also, where do *saw* and *sore* sound at all similar?

Comment: @Marthaª: In Britain, at least.

Comment: @Marthaª In most of England, Wales, South Africa, Australia and most of New Zealand, I would not expect to be able to distinguish _saw_ from _sore_ at all.  Most Americans, Canadians, Irish and Scottish will pronounce these two words differently.

Answer (score 14):

It is called a [rebus](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rebus?view=uk).

> a puzzle in which words are represented by combinations of pictures and individual letters; for instance, apex might be represented by a picture of an ape followed by a letter X.