# Name of wordplay similar to a pun but where one word is made up

Tags: puns

An example would be most clear:

Let's say a company finds a new way to help people communicate.  They call their company `kamunik8r`

Since `kamunik8r` is a made up word that is meant to sound like 'communicator', does that make this a pun?  What is this?

Answer (score 4):

It is a type of **[rebus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)**.

The rebus principle is defined as

> using existing symbols, such as pictograms, purely for their sounds regardless of their meaning, to represent new words.

Such symbols can include numerals or even letters, such as *C U later* (for *see you later*).

Comment: See also @cornbread ninja 麵包忍's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/is-there-a-name-for-this-method-of-writing-that-includes-pictograms/81643#81643)

Comment: Also​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ written: CU L8R​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: hmmm what if it doesn't have the `8`-- `kamunikator` for example?

Comment: Then it's not a rebus, just a non-standard spelling.