# Substituting special characters or numerals for letters/word parts

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, slang

Is there a word or phrase to describe a substituting a dingbat, special character or number for a letter or portion of a word?

Examples:

> The Chicago Bulls successfully achieved a **3peat**.
>
> "In 1999, Tom Jermoluk stepped down as CEO of **Excite@Home**."
>
> **Ke$ha** is the stage name of Kesha Rose Sebert.

I thought of "letter substitution", but that can also refer to a [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words such as *Micro$oft* and *Kei$ha* are examples of [satiric misspelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satiric_misspelling):

> A satiric misspelling is an intentional misspelling of a word, phrase or name for a rhetorical purpose. This is often done by replacing a letter with another letter (for example, k replacing c), or symbol (for example, $ replacing s, @ replacing a, or ¢ replacing c). Satiric misspelling is found particularly in informal writing on the Internet, but can also be found in some serious political writing that opposes the status quo.

The term also [finds mention on Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=satiric%20misspelling).

*3-peat* is a contraction of [three-peat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-peat)<sup>1</sup>. From there, it's simply a question of replacing the three with the numeral (like we do with two-year-old/2-year-old). *3peat* (sans hyphen) could perhaps be classified under one or more of [leetspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), [SMS language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language), or as a [grammargram or rebus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/what-is-xlnc-an-example-of).

I don't believe that Excite@Home really qualifies as it's effectively a portmanteau of the names of two companies, Excite and @Home. The latter is an ISP and its use of *@* is self-evident.

---

<sup>1</sup>(the construction *threepeat* has apparently been registered as a trademark – threepeatedly `:s`

Comment: Good an$wer, coleopterist! Th@'s 1 H3LL of a find!

Comment: I like this answer, but the wikipedia article seems to indicate that the term applies only when the usage is specifically satirical.

Comment: @Marcus: If you add "[leet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)" to "satiric misspelling", you'll have an even broader set of examples.

Comment: @Marcus_33 Good point. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is like an mash-up between a pun and a typographical rebus.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's not really one easy term for it. This covers the gamut of choices though.