# Is there a term for a shorthand word formed by pronunciation?

Tags: single-word-requests

The chat shorthand that started me thinking on this was `oic` which represents `Oh, I see.`

This is not an Acronym or an Initialism, as both of those are based on spelling.

This is not just a shortened form of a word, like “ex.” for “example”.  Though that is just an Abbreviation, neither an acronym nor an initialism, it is still based on spelling.

This is not an Onomatopoeia, a word crafted to be similar to the sound it represents, as pronouncing this would be so close to the sound a pig makes. `oink`

This is shorthand needing another way of interpretation to be properly understood.  Abbreviation is the closest term that I know for something like this, but it does not seem to fit.  Does anyone know a term for this kind of word?  Just curious.  Perhaps giving it a term would legitimize it too much.

Comment: You could consider them a form of a rebus, or a grammagram.  See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44003

Comment: And [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204086/is-iou-an-abbreviation-an-acronym-or-an-initialism/204119#204119)

Comment: 1337 speak comes to mind....

Comment: Not knowing what to call it, I did not know how to search for a duplicate question.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "Tironian notes" which includes notations we use to stand in for long or complex words such as "RIP" on a tombstone, or "viz", "et" and "etc".